# Nested route disappear immediately instead of playing :leave animation

Tags: angular, routes, angular-animations

I have outer routes: `/posts` and `/about`. `/posts` route has nested routes: `/` and `/pages/:pageNumber`.

When navigating between nested routes (`/` and `/pages/:pageNumber`) animations work well. But when navigating to `/about` nested route immediately disappears.

`animateChild()` doesn't help. In parent router component animation:

```
transition(':leave', [
  query('@*', animateChild()),
  animate('/*some easing*/', style({/*some styles*/}))
])
```

This causes error `query("@*") returned zero elements.`. So nested route is removed immediately, parent component can't see it.

Angular version: **4.2.2**

Comment: Been looking all over the webs for a solution to this. Seems like it should be a common occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of the problem was that, when navigating from /page1 to /page2, in page2.component.ts I was loading some data from the server **in the constructor**. Moving that code to ngOnInit solved this issue, after 2 weeks of breaking my head.